# Securing MS Access Database

Tags: ms-access

Guys I'm working on a local system project where I'd use Microsoft access as the database storage.

This application may be distributed among several users with different access layer control.

The direct method to secure the database from manual update is to put a password lock, however I came across this software today: https://www.accessrecoverytool.com/how_to_recover_access_password.html

It simply cracked my password with special character instantly.

May I know if there's any better way to secure a ms access mdb file?

Thank you.

Comment: mdb files have been outdated since 2007. They don't offer good encryption. Can you just update to an accdb file?

Comment: @Chor, are willing to consider a third party product?

Answer (score 1):

there are many considerations when it comes to security.  as E.v.A. has already posted, at a minimum, don't use the old .mdb file format and instead use .accdb or .accde (to compile the front) or.accdr (user only has runtime version).

whether or not the password method for the .accdb has also been publicly cracked I cannot say as I do not monitor such things. Assuming it is the data you are concerned about (rather than the front end code) - then the accdb can encrypt the data so that one must have a front end, with the embedded pw in order to see the data.

One can always put the back end data onto SQL Server Express to then rely upon the SQL Server's security feature set.